# How to parse AEM DAM JSON InputStream and create JSON Object

Tags: aem

I have a requirement where-in I have to read the JSON file which exists in AEM DAM. So, I have created a query to read the JSON file in inputStream. With the below line of code, i could get the JSON file in Input Stream. Now, I need to know If there is any standard library to read the input stream and create the JSON Object?

```
InputStream is = asset.getOriginal().getStream();
```

Comment: There are many libraries out there for serializing/deserializing JSON, the most notable is google’s Gson library: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: FYI, it is not as simple as you may think because of how AEM might store the data. If you are loading the file through the DAM vs CRX/content deployment, the asset might vary in its type and metadata. You can utilize the InputStream by loading the JSON file through the resource resolver or other general ways of pulling in those JSON files. Just keep in mind that you have to be careful how you load it because it isn't straight forward in AEM's DAM. You might have to access the jcr:content/jcr:data

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries for serializing/deserializing JSON in java, the most notable is Google’s Gson: https://github.com/google/gson

I’ve used gson in all my AEM projects that require JSON manipulation. That does not mean you can’t use another library.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above there are many libraries like Google’s Gson, Jackson an etc. I think the below code snippet can help you,

```
public JSONObject getJsonFromFile(ResourceResolver resolver,String filePath){
   JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
    Resource resource=  resolver.getResource(filePath);
    try {
        Node jcnode = resource.adaptTo(Node.class).getNode("jcr:content");
        InputStream content=jcnode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;            
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(content,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

    }catch (RepositoryException | JSONException | IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```