# Best way to read AEM DAM JSON file

Tags: aem

I have a JSON file stored in AEM DAM. I want to read the AEM file and parse it and store the data in the list. Is there any standard apis available to read the JSON file from AEM DAM?

Comment: This might be a duplicate. The user already asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121569/how-to-parse-aem-dam-json-inputstream-and-create-json-object

Comment: Please read the community guidelines on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You upload file in the dam,apps or in etc and provided the path in the getJSON method to access that json file using jquery. as shown in the below example.you can change the path where ever u want.

```
$.getJSON("/apps/uopx/components/top-Program-carousel/clientlibs/js/data.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data.topPrograms, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value.business[0].learnMore);
    });
})
```